# Apply class to selected LI and ALL previous LIs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I select an LI I want to apply a class to the selected LI and ALL previous LIS, right now I only have it working for the selected LI and one previous LI any help to select all previous

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/ym5wr/

**jQuery**

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('li').css({ "background-color":"#fff" });
    $(this).prev().andSelf().css({ "background-color":"#ccc" });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ym5wr/1/)***

Use [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) instead of `.prev()`

```
$(this).prevAll().andSelf().css({ "background-color":"#ccc" });
```

Or, since `andSelf()` is deprecated in version 1.8, use [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)

```
$(this).prevAll().addBack().css({ "background-color":"#ccc" });
```

Comment: Just a note: [andSelf has been deprecated and use addBack instead](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/).